# How to create Flutter minimized app controls

Tags: flutter

*Note: this is **not** a push notification*

I would like to know how I can create a minimized controls-widget for my Flutter app. A place where I can add a few buttons, examples are:

- Play/pause, next, previous (for a music app)
- Start, stop (for a timer app)
- Single input box (for a quick reply section)

Most music player apps have this functionality, when you "minimize" the app, then you end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to make a native implementation for each platform (Java/Kotlin and Objective-C/Swift). Then use MethodChannels for interaction with Dart.

Comment: Flutter now offers the ability to implement flutter views in native applications (FlutterView class). If you want to have a view designed in the Flutter and have all the logic there you should create a notification on native side, and pin flutter code by custom view (in this case FlutterView). More info -> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps
The MethodChannel mentioned above can be used to control the notification (show, hide)

Comment: Are there any new solutions or a package that provides this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) plugin. This enables the Flutter app send playback requests to platform-specific media standard callbacks.